# foreach loop highlight cells from database

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, forms

I'm wondering if my code could be easier with a foreach loop. my code thusfar:
the purpose is to read the values in the MYSQL table, and if the anwser is "NEE" display the background color in RED. my code works but it is very long..

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); //The Blank string is 
the password
mysql_select_db('heijsDB');

$query = "SELECT * FROM hygieneaanvoer"; //You don't need a ; like you do in 
SQL
$result = mysql_query($query);

//List the Columns for the Report 
if(! $result ) {
           die('Could display data: ' . mysql_error());
        }

echo "<table border='1' class='w3-panel'> 
<fieldset>hygiëne/GMP aduit Aanvoer</fieldset>
<tr> 
<th>Datum</th> 
<th>Controleur</th> 
<th>controleur</th>
<th>Revisie</th> 
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>4</th>
<th>5</th>
<th>6</th>
<th>7</th>
<th>8</th>
<th>9</th>
<th>10</th>
<th>11</th>
<th>12</th>
<th>13</th>
<th>14</th>
<th>15</th>
</tr>"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
 echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>" . $row['datum'] . "</td>"; 
 echo "<td>" . $row['controleur'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['codering'] . "</td>"; 
 echo "<td>" . $row['revisie'] . "</td>";
 if($row['q1']=='NEE') // [val1] can be 'approved'
     echo "<td style='background-color: #e21010;'>".$row['q1']."</td>";
else echo "<td>".$row['q1']."</td>";
    if($row['q2']=='NEE') // [val1] can be 'approved'
     echo "<td style='background-color: #e21010;'>".$row['q2']."</td>";
else echo "<td>".$row['q2']."</td>";
if($row['q3']=='NEE') // [val1] can be 'approved'
     echo "<td style='background-color: #e21010;'>".$row['q3']."</td>";
else echo "<td>".$row['q3']."</td>";
if($row['q4']=='NEE') // [val1] can be 'approved'
     echo "<td style='background-color: #e21010;'>".$row['q4']."</td>";
else echo "<td>".$row['q4']."</td>";
if($row['q5']=='NEE') // [val1] can be 'approved'
     echo "<td style='background-color: #e21010;'>".$row['q5']."</td>";
else echo "<td>".$row['q5']."</td>";
if($row['q6']=='NEE') // [val1] can be 'approved'
     echo "<td style='background-color: #e21010;'>".$row['q6']."</td>";
else echo "<td>".$row['q6']."</td>";
if($row['q7']=='NEE') // [val1] can be 'approved'
     echo "<td style='background-color: #e21010;'>".$row['q7']."</td>";
else echo "<td>".$row['q7']."</td>";
if($row['q8']=='NEE') // [val1] can be 'approved'
     echo "<td style='background-color: #e21010;'>".$row['q8']."</td>";
else echo "<td>".$row['q8']."</td>";
if($row['q9']=='NEE') // [val1] can be 'approved'
     echo "<td style='background-color: #e21010;'>".$row['q9']."</td>";
else echo "<td>".$row['q9']."</td>";
if($row['q10']=='NEE') // [val1] can be 'approved'
     echo "<td style='background-color: #e21010;'>".$row['q10']."</td>";
else echo "<td>".$row['q10']."</td>";
if($row['q11']=='NEE') // [val1] can be 'approved'
     echo "<td style='background-color: #e21010;'>".$row['q11']."</td>";
else echo "<td>".$row['q11']."</td>";
if($row['q12']=='NEE') // [val1] can be 'approved'
     echo "<td style='background-color: #e21010;'>".$row['q12']."</td>";
else echo "<td>".$row['q12']."</td>";
if($row['q13']=='NEE') // [val1] can be 'approved'
     echo "<td style='background-color: #e21010;'>".$row['q13']."</td>";
else echo "<td>".$row['q13']."</td>";
if($row['q14']=='NEE') // [val1] can be 'approved'
     echo "<td style='background-color: #e21010;'>".$row['q14']."</td>";
else echo "<td>".$row['q14']."</td>";
if($row['q15']=='NEE') // [val1] can be 'approved'
     echo "<td style='background-color: #e21010;'>".$row['q15']."</td>";
else echo "<td>".$row['q15']."</td>";
 echo "</tr>"; 
 } 
echo "</table>";

   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hygieneaanvoer")or die('Could display data: ' . mysql_error());;

echo "<table border='1' class='w3-panel'> 
<fieldset>hygiëne/GMP aduit Aanvoer</fieldset>
<tr> 
<th>Datum</th> 
<th>Controleur</th> 
<th>controleur</th>
<th>Revisie</th>";

for ($i=1;$i<=15;$i++){
    echo '<th>'.$i.'</th>';
} 
echo "</tr>"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  { 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['datum'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['controleur'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['codering'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['revisie'] . "</td>";
    for ($j=1;$j<=15;$j++){
        echo "<td ".(($row['q'.$j] == 'NEE') ? "style='background-color: #e21010;'" : "" ).">".$row['q'.$j]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for anwsering my question :)!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is just create a single variable that you'd use for setting the style of all rows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $style_string = "";
    if($row['q1']=='NEE') {
        $style_string = "style='background-color: #e21010;'";
    }

    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['datum'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['controleur'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['codering'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['revisie'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td " . $style_string . ">" . $row['q1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td " . $style_string . ">" . $row['q2'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td " . $style_string . ">" . $row['q3'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td " . $style_string . ">" . $row['q4'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td " . $style_string . ">" . $row['q5'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td " . $style_string . ">" . $row['q6'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td " . $style_string . ">" . $row['q7'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td " . $style_string . ">" . $row['q8'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td " . $style_string . ">" . $row['q9'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td " . $style_string . ">" . $row['q10'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td " . $style_string . ">" . $row['q11'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td " . $style_string . ">" . $row['q12'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td " . $style_string . ">" . $row['q13'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td " . $style_string . ">" . $row['q14'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td " . $style_string . ">" . $row['q15']. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
 }
```

(Or just set the background color of the `<tr>`)

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for anwsering my question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the class to the `td` like this

```
echo "<td class='". $row['q15'] . "'>".$row['q15']."</td>";
```

Add css like this

```
.NEE {background-color: #e21010;}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!